# Gatsby buildObjectType for array of items

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I have a field that contains an array of Strings - in this case it's an array of filenames, but it could be IDs or any identifier. I'd like to use `buildObjectType` to resolve these Strings to another Node. In other words, resolve an array of `String`s to an array of external Nodes.

I have used `buildObjectType` to resolve a Node from a field containing a single identifier, but haven't been able to get it working when the field is an array of IDs. In the case of a single identifier the resolver is something like:

```
context.nodeModel
  .getAllNodes({ type: "ChildYaml" })
  .find(child => child.slug === source.child)
```

Now I need to iterate over an array and resolve each item.

Here's an example of my field in a `ParentYaml` file

```
files:
  - filename1
  - filename2
  - filename3
  - filename4
```

In `gatsby-config`:

```
exports.createSchemaCustomization = ({ actions, schema }) => {
  const { createTypes } = actions

  const typeDefs = [
    schema.buildObjectType({
      name: "ParentYaml",
      fields: {
        files: {
          type: "ChildYaml",
          resolve: (source, args, context, info) => {
            // Iterate over context and resolve each item to a filename
          },
        },
      },
    })
  ]

  createTypes(typeDefs)
}
```

I have tried the following `resolve`, unsuccessfully. This gets a File Node, but not the `ChildYaml`.

```
resolve: (source, args, context, info) => {
  return source.files.map((fileRef) => {
    return context.nodeModel
      .getAllNodes({ type: "File" })
      .find(file => file.name === fileRef)
  })
},
```

I have also tried a method to resolve the `ChildYaml` (instead of `File`) using the `slug`. This produces a similar result - the `resolve` returns an array of the desired Nodes, but those Nodes are not available in my page context.

How can I resolve Nodes of an array?

Answer (score 2):

One of the reasons I love Stack Overflow, and the question-asking process - it encourages you to think of the problem in a different way, take a step back and boil the issue down to the basics.

In writing the question and re-reading it later I took a different approach and tried [Gatsby's `@link` directive](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/schema-customization#foreign-key-fields).

This format replaced the verbose `schema.buildObjectType` syntax with the following:

```
type ParentYaml implements Node {
   files: [ChildYaml] @link(by: "slug")
},
```

which did exactly what I wanted - the `files` field now resolves each file into it's own `ChildYaml` Node.